# Kotlin, Android, how to debug coroutines correctly?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to debug my coroutines, and breakpoints placed into suspend function don't work. Pls help me understand why.

Working with Android Studio.

Ok, I launch a coroutine from viewModelScope:

```
    viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
        when(val result = interactor.getAllWords()){...}
    }
```

In `getAllWords()` I wrote:

```
    override suspend fun getAllWords(): WordResult {
        val words = mutableListOf<Word>()

        when (val wordsResult = getAllWordsWithoutFiltersApplying()) {}

        ...

        return getWordsWithSelectedPattern()
```

I have two suspend functions: `getAllWordsWithoutFiltersApplying()` and `getWordsWithSelectedPattern()`. I have a breakpoints into both of them, but they did't trigger in debug mode.

At the same time, line `val words = mutableListOf<Word>()` is triggering, when I put breakpoint to its line.

And, if I put some log stuff into "untracing" function, they will be work. I say it to make it clear, suspend function works. Breakpoints are not.

What should I do to debug them?

*Screenshot added. Look at the left side with row of icons. Why my lines are not available?

[image]

Comment: Can you post full body of `getAllWordsWithoutFiltersApplying()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Based on your sample code, you switch the coroutine context between `MAIN` and `IO` so when you set the breakpoint, make sure the `suspend` option is `ALL`

***To show the option of the breakpoint. Set a breakpoint with the left click of your mouse, and then right click your mouse on the breakpoint.***

If you are using the JetBrain IDE, according to the [document](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-debugging-coroutines/), when you set the breakpoint to make sure the `suspend` option is `ALL` not thread. it works for me.

[image]

and more detail you can check the [document](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-debugging-coroutines/)

[image]

Comment: very helpful answer..this must be the accepted answer

Comment: Doesn't work for flows.. Using co routines 1.4.0 with the android dependencies included.

Comment: Why isn't this the default behavior?

Comment: Stuck at `Evaluating...`

Answer (score 3):

It still does not work for me because I run the app first then attach the debugger, but when I use debug instead, it works.

Comment: The problem is in unit tests...

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but this is for those people who made similar mistakes like me. I've also faced this issue recently and the root cause was related to dependencies. Actually I added **coroutine core dependency** but I forget to add **coroutine android dependency**. Please make sure both dependencies are present in your gradle file as shown below.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.4"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.4'
```

Comment: as far as I know kotlinx-coroutines-android contains only Main dispatcher. How does it help with debugging?

Answer (score 1):

I had forgot `minifyEnabled` set to **true** in my `build.gradle` file

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
    }
    debug {
      minifyEnabled true <- Should be false for these breakpoints to work
    }
  }
```