# How to debug Kotlin source code in AndroidStudio？

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to debug the source code of the Kotlin library in AndroidStudio，such as debugging the source code in kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.3.jar.
I found that breakpoints in the source code do not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin, Android, how to debug coroutines correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345012/kotlin-android-how-to-debug-coroutines-correctly)