# Cannot see coroutine tab in the debugger tool window

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to debug coroutines and followed the below resources to enable in Android Studio,

- [Jetbrain bug issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-575)
- [Jetbrain blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-debugging-coroutines/)
- [Jetbrain doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/debug-coroutines-with-idea.html)

but unfortunately, I don't see the coroutine tab at all!! (below screenshot)

Coroutine library version,

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
```

and my Kotlin plugin version is 1.4.21

Why do I still not see the coroutine debug tab?

[image]

Comment: i've also been unable to see it in Android Studio. My best guess would be it needs a newer intellij build (which would be available in Android Studio Canary possibly). I would try the same thing in the current IntelliJ build. If it works there, you may need to wait for a new Android Studio build (or try the current beta/canary)

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @IvanGarza 4.1.1

Comment: I am working on a non-android project and it is not showing up either. I even reset all settings to defaults, deleted all caches, checked for updates 20 times, but the tab remains absent (IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1 RC (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-203.6682.115, built on December 23, 2020, Kotlin plugin 203-1.4.21-release-IJ5981.133)

Comment: Possibly related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43994

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know coroutine debugger is not yet available on android at all. This question was brought up during the kotlin event in October and [here](https://youtu.be/bz33QjVUJbs?t=2500) is the answer from the kotlin devs.

**Update:** coroutines debugger for android has been finally [announced](https://youtu.be/etLUpHvhNZw?t=505) on Google IO 2021!

Comment: Use this as refarence 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345012/kotlin-android-how-to-debug-coroutines-correctly

Comment: When did they actualy add this? Because i am on the latest kotlin, android studio and courotines version as of time of wring this and i still dont see the ability to debug on courotines

Comment: Sitting here in 2023 still can't find this tab

Comment: My guess is this has something to do with it
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-debug#debug-agent-and-android

Comment: Sitting here in 2024 still can not find this tab, yeah!